# SQL Server: Update table row using merge

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I am using trying to update a table from dynamic variable but I always got Incorrect syntax, can you help me where did I made a mistake?

This is the message when I run the query.

> select convert(varchar(55),refdate)+'-'+convert(varchar(55),refcount) FROM [gen_048_MAR2016]
>
> ```
>       MERGE gen_048_MAR2016 as target             USING #temp1 as source
>           ON target.refcount = source.refnum
>               AND sourc3e.tsql = target.refcount
>         WHEN MATCHED THEN
>           UPDATE
>               SET
>               target.stat = source.stat
>               target.statdate = source.statdate           WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
>         INSERT (stat, statdate)
>         VALUES (S.stat, S.statdate)                   
>             ; Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near 'target'.
> ```
>
> > ERROR: Incorrect syntax near 'target'.

I didn't write the whole query so I just copy and paste the party where I think I made an error.

```
CREATE TABLE #records(
         [index] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
        ,refnum varchar(200)
        ,stat varchar(200)
        ,statdate varchar(200)
    )

insert into #records (refnum, stat, statdate) 
select 
dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',0),
dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',3),
dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',4)

from #temp1

declare @refnum varchar(100)
declare @stat varchar(100)
declare @statdate varchar(100)
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
declare @index int


WHILE (@index <= (SELECT MAX([index]) FROM #records))


    BEGIN

    set @stat = (select stat from #records where [index] = @index)
    select @stat
    set @statdate = (select statdate from #records where [index] = @index)
    select @statdate

    set @refnum = (select refnum from #records where [index] = @index)
    set @refnum = replace(@refnum, 'F', '')
    select @refnum

    set @sql = '
        MERGE '+@sourceTable+' T
        USING #temp1 S
            ON T.refcount = S.refnum
                AND S.tsql = T.refcount
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE
                SET 
                T.stat = S.stat
                T.statdate = S.statdate
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
          INSERT (stat, statdate)
          VALUES (S.stat, S.statdate)                   
            ;'
            select @refnum, @stat, @statdate
            print @sql
            exec (@sql)

        SELECT 'File has been successfully uploaded', @fileDate,'success' as msg

      set @index = @index + 1

   END
```

I didn't put the `@sourceTable` string to lessen the codes, but I can add it anytime if that info is needed.

Comment: A MERGE statement must be terminated by a semi-colon (;). Did you do that?

Comment: Edit your question and print out the `merge` statement after variable substitution.

Comment: Yes, you're right~! @DeepanshuKalra

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry, I am new in SQL but I think I already made a print before the `exec` statement or do I need to print it again?

Comment: @VinceOsana Gordon meant, you need to share the Merge statement so that he can tell you whats the problem there. And you can get the SQL just by using PRINT instead of EXEC.

Comment: Ohhh... sorry, is it right if I just post the screenshot of the result?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Can someone tell me why this error message occur? `; Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near 'target'.`

Comment: Add 'USE YourDataBaseNameHere GO' before MERGE statement. Also check 'SELECT name, compatibility_level 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = db_name();' on database where you trying to do MERGE.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your actual dynamic SQL after variable substitution you use `target` and `source` reserved words as table aliases. Use square brackets `[target]` or better still just `T` as you do in "the whole query" code sample.
2. You are missing comma in dynamic SQL after `T.stat = S.stat`.